# How to match string that does not contain a specific string

Tags: regex, go, regex-lookarounds

I would like to write regexp in Go to match a string only if it does not contain a specific substring (-numinput) and contain another specific string (-setup).

Example, for inputStr

The following type of strings should NOT match because -numinput is present

```
str = "axxx yy  -setup  abc -numinput 12345678 aaa"
```

The following type of strings should match as -setup is present and -numinput is not present

```
str = "axxx yy  -setup  abc aaa"
```

The following type of strings should not match because  -setup is not present even though -numinput is not present

```
str = "axxx yy abc aaa"
```

I came across some posts like [Regular expression to match a line that doesn't contain a word?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/406230/regular-expression-to-match-a-line-that-doesnt-contain-a-word)

But, I just dont understand how to do it in Golang

Comment: Why not use `strings.Contains()`? Regex in Go does not allow lookarounds and what you want will look like a really ugly regex.

Comment: Regex is completely the wrong tool for this.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to parse command line flags, consider using the flag package

https://golang.org/pkg/flag/

For general string related functionality, considers the strings package

https://golang.org/pkg/strings/

In your case:

```
strings.Contains(str, "-setup") && !strings.Contains(str, "-numinput")
```